# Covert in C# DateTime from US to UK format

Tags: c#-4.0

```
string DateAndTime = Cells[1].Text; // Output is 3/18/2020 3:00:18 PM

DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(DateAndTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Error: string was not recognized as a valid datetime

Current string is this 3/18/2020 3:00:18 PM

I want to convert and parse it to `DateTime` as `18/03/2020 15:00:18`

Answer (score 2):

`ParseExact` does exactly that, parses the string using the *exact* specification you provide.  And, per your specification, "18" isn't a valid month.  It sounds like you want to swap the month and day identifiers (and only use `M` instead of `MM` for the month, and use `h` for the single-digit 12-hour clock, and add `tt` for the AM/PM specification):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateAndTime, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
```

Once it's parsed as a `DateTime` you can *output* the value in any format you like.  For example:

```
DT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

But your *input* format very much is not "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss".  For parsing you need to match the input format, not the intended downstream format.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(DateAndTime, new CultureInfo("en-US"));