# Date Conversion fails in C# via Parameter adding (SqlDbType.DateTime)

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, ssis-2017

I am new to C#. I have this statement that fails:

```
dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@createdTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

The value in the createdTime is: 1/18/2012 11:54:11 AM
After a lot of troubleshooting I was able to narrow down the issue. It will work *IF* I change the value to: 2012-01-18 11:54:01 AM. So it doesn't work with the format. I found the issue but how can I fix this issue? I mean, the DateTime format is what it is.

Here is more of my code to explain:

```
        dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        dbCmd.CommandText = sqlCmd;
        
        dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@FullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@createdTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

Comment: Why are you passing a `string` and not a C# `DateTime`? Passing a `DateTime` would solve your problem 100%.

Comment: Note that `DateTime` in C# and the corresponding column in SQL Server (unless the DB field is text) has no concept of date / time format. That's something that happens when you render the value as a string.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar thank you for the reply. It is a string/text, I cannot change it to a DateTime. The data is coming in as string.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar is there no way to set/define a format? to go from DD-MM-YYYY to MM-DD-YYYY? This is kinda stuck now.

Comment: Well, you could parse it to a C# `DateTime`, but if you mean that you have a requirement to keep the exact string value as it was provided, then you should store it as a textual data type in the database.

Comment: `DateTime` in C# is a single `long` value, and components (year, month, day, etc.) are computed from this. Any human-readable representation you see is a result of converting it to a `string`. The specific details on the SQL Server side differ a little, but the idea is generally the same.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thank you, but honestly mate, not sure to go from "1/18/2012 11:54:11 AM" into "2012-01-18 11:54:01 AM". A lot more complicated than I thought.

Comment: *"The data is coming in as string"*. Coming in from where exactly? How? The issue is not the parameter but the data, but you have shown us nothing relating to the data.

Comment: You could use the first half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60743372/3181933) to convert your string to a `DateTime`. Then you can pass that object to your database. If you need a specific format to send/display when you read from the database, you can convert it to a `string` again.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar given I am using TextFieldParser, this did not work. As it only accepts strings.

Comment: You can parse a date with `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`. Do not expect SQL to convert it for you: while it can do it, it does it badly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the value explicitly in C# so the db parameter contains a DateTime, not a string:

```
dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@createdTime", SqlDbType.DateTime)
  .Value = DateTime.ParseExact(theVariableHoldingStringDateTime, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If your use of Add there is just setting up a parameter that you're later giving a value to in a loop:

```
for each line in text file parser blah blah

  dbCmd.Parameters["@createdTime"]
    .Value = DateTime.ParseExact(theVariableHoldingStringDateTime, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```